# Changing the font color of the combined text and formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a value in A1 cell which is 22

I want to have in A2 cell a text like the following in the image

[image: combined formatted text and formula]

Comment: You need `VBA` to do that.

Comment: Is it possible without VBA?

Comment: No, not possible.

Comment: Can I use TEXT() function to change the color of a text?

Comment: As per my best known there is no built-in function that changes font color. Text function changes data format.

Comment: Also, be aware that even when using VBA, it is required to have a text string in that cell in order to differently format each character.  So you will need to create a VBA Sub (not a Function), that creates the string; writes it into the cell; and then formats the specific characters as you desire.

Comment: I found a workaround solution to use two textboxes one for "UPDATE: There are " and one text box for "22 governorates in the country" and link the second textbox to the cell A1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround solution to use two textboxes one for "UPDATE: There are " and one text box for "22 governorates in the country" and link the second textbox to the cell A1